# Photo upload from dataURL rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

How can i upload photo from dataURL using carrierwave? uploading from remote url not working. I tried

```
@photo.remote_photo_url = params[:data_url]
```

Comment: Did you run `@photo.save!` afterwards?

Comment: can you post full stack / messages error?

Comment: error: Photo trying to download a file which is not served over HTTP

Comment: @selivandex what the url look like